# Soundcloud API doesn't explicitly support pagination with json

Tags: json, api, pagination, soundcloud

Specific example I was working with:

http://api.soundcloud.com/users/dubstep/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

You'll get their first 50 tracks, but there is not next-href object like what you see in the  [xml version](http://api.soundcloud.com/users/dubstep/tracks.xml?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID).

However, you can use offset and limit and it works as expected- but then I would need to "blindly" crawl through tracks until there are no more tracks, unlike with the XML version which gives you the "next page" of results.  I wouldn't have even noticed it was paginated except by chance when I was searching the json object and noticed there was exactly 50 tracks (which is suspiciously even).

Is there a plan to support the next-href tag in json? Am I missing something? is it a bug that it's missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an undocumented parameter you can use `linked_partitioning=1`, that will add `next_href` to the response.

http://api.soundcloud.com/users/dubstep/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&linked_partitioning=1

Answer (score 1):

for ex :

```
// build our API URL
$clientid = "Your API Client ID"; // Your API Client ID
$userid = "/ IDuser"; // ID of the user you are fetching the information for

// Grab the contents of the URL
//more php get
$number="1483";

$offset=1300;
$limit=200;

$soundcloud_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/tracks.json?client_id={$clientid}&offset={$offset}&limit={$limit}";
$tracks_json = file_get_contents($soundcloud_url);
$tracks = json_decode($tracks_json);


foreach ($tracks as $track) {
    echo "<pre>";
     echo $track->title . ":";
    echo $track->permalink_url . "";
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sI've seen this code is supposed to help (this is in Ruby):

```
# start paging through results, 100 at a time
tracks = client.get('/tracks', :order => 'created_at', :limit => page_size,
                    :linked_partitioning => 1)
tracks.each { |t| puts t.title }
```

However, the first set of results will show and i'll even see the "next_href" at the end of the response, but what are you supposed to do, to make the next set of results show?

Comment: The data from `next_href`  should be a link to the next API URL. I don't work much with ruby so I'm not sure how to translate that data into something your ruby "client" object can handle