# Soundcloud API returns less items than the given limit (although there are more)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I use the Soundcloud JavaScript SDK to get the favorites of a specific user.

Unfortunately it does not return the expected amount of items, even if I provide a limit (default is 50).

For example the following code returns 197 items, though the amount of favorites is over 900.

```
SC.get('/users/3684392/favorites',
      { 'limit': 200, 'offset': 0 },
      function(data){
          console.log(data.length);
      }
);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AY4qp/1/)

Is there no guarantee of the returned item amount?

Comment: It seems that the Problem is still not fixed ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been having the same problem.  It seems like the limit parameter is broken for /favorites endpoints.

Here is how you can get all of a user's favorites, despite the broken limit parameter:

```
var req = {
    path: '/users/3684392/favorites',
    params: { 
        limit: 200, 
        offset: 0 
    }
};

var getAll = function(req, collection, callback) {
    SC.get('req.path', { 
        'limit': req.params.limit, 
        'offset': req.params.offset 
    }, function(data){
        collection = collection.concat(data);

        if (data.length === 0) {
            callback(collection);
        }
        else {
            req.params.offset += data.length;
            getAll(req, collection, callback);
        }
    });

getAll(req, [], function(collection) {
    console.log(collection);
});
```

[a fork of your jsFiddle using the same technique](http://jsfiddle.net/4Cy3r/1/)

If you are trying to get a specific number of results, you could also adjust the limit.

For instance, if you want 200 and get 196, set the offset to 196 and limit to 4.  Check it again after the next call.  You'd probably be better off just waiting for them to fix it, though.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad that the limit option does not work correctly :(

Comment: Bootleg, but it works! Would love to see what the logic looks like on the SoundCloud side to have this happen ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code here:

```
var page_size = 200;

var getstring = '/users/3684392/favorites';

SC.get(getstring,{ limit: page_size }, function(favs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {    
        $('#result').append(favs[i].title + ': ' + favs[i].permalink_url + '<br/>');
    }
});

SC.get(getstring,{ limit: page_size, offset: page_size}, function(favs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
        $('#result').append(favs[i].title + ': ' + favs[i].permalink_url + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/gwpAM/

Comment: If you add `console.log(favs)` to the two SC.get() calls or show it in #results, you will see that they do not return 200 items.
http://jsfiddle.net/EV6A8/

Answer (score 0):

we are currently in process of redoing some internal parts of the API so this is a bit clunky (while you can still hack around it as suggested by other replies).

Menawhile I'd recommend using special pagination param (to be documented soon) – https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259849/236135, so your link'd be:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3684392/favorites.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&linked_partitioning=1
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that you're working on it.
Unfortunately the linked_partitioning option is affected as well (retrieves the same results) and stops before getting all of the requested tracks (favorites). 
As long as the issue remains, I will use the solution of @hedgerh. Hoping to hear from you soon! :)